# 最初に現れた「いずれかの文字列」より後の文字列を取得したい

Tags: php

**やりたいこと**
ある文章で、「大阪店」か「東京店」が最初に現れた地点より後の文字列を取得したいです。
対象文章に、「大阪店」は、0回か1回含まれています。
対象文章に、「東京店」は、0回か1回含まれています。

---

**具体例**
当サイトでは、コーディングやアルゴリズムなど、主に大阪店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。
→「に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。」を取得したい

当サイトでは、コーディングやアルゴリズムなど、主に東京店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。
→「に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。」を取得したい

大阪店では、コーディングやアルゴリズムなど、主に東京店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。
→「では、コーディングやアルゴリズムなど、主に東京店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。」を取得したい

当サイトでは、コーディングや東京店など、主に大阪店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。
→「など、主に大阪店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。」を取得したい

---

**分からない点**
最初に現れた「文字列」より後の文字列は、[strstr](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.strstr.php)で取得できたのですが、最初に現れた「いずれかの文字列」より後という条件は、どう書けばよいですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は [PHP: preg_match](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.preg-match.php) を使う方法です。

```php
<?php

$sentence = '当サイトでは、コーディングや東京店など、主に大阪店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。';

if (preg_match("/(東京|大阪)店(.*)$/", $sentence, $matches)) {
  echo "{$matches[2]}\n";
} else {
  echo "not found\n";
}

// 実行結果
など、主に大阪店に関する問題のサポートを目標としています。
```

Answer (score 1):

`$result = preg_replace('/^.*?(大阪店|東京店)/', '', $source);`
これでどうでしょう。

`$source`に「大阪店」も「東京店」も現れない場合は`$result`は`$source`と同じになってしまいますが。